# Check any element of an array inside a list

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, any

Assume I got an array, created by a pandas dataframe with `array = df.index.values` and looks like following:

```
array
array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
       'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], dtype=object)
```

and I got a python list looks like following:

```
list = ['AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'A']
```

---

Looking for a function, which does following:

**If any element of array is also in list, give me True. If not give me False.**

PS: I am not looking for finding the element. Just want to know if such element exist.

Comment: any([a in list for a in array]) Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: It is not the same question @jezrael. There were 2 list compared. I am looking for an pandas function which iterates over its array items and checks if that element is inside a list.

Comment: @Icedkk - It not exist in pandas. Need all solutions from dupes. Or can you expalin more?

Comment: @jezrael updated?

Comment: @Icedkk - I am a bit confused `Array = array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
               'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], dtype=object)` is `Series`? or numpy array? What return in real data `print (type(Array))` ?

Comment: If series then `Array.isin(List).any()` should working.

Comment: array is pandas `df.index.values` and checked again it is `numpy.ndarray` and it returns a normal list with print.

Comment: So solution is `df.index.isin(List).any()`

Comment: TY!!!!! Wanna write the solution? @jezrael

Comment: But also working all solutions from dupes, becasue array should be coerced to list

Comment: hmmm, can you add to question `array` is `df.index.values` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179172/discussion-between-icedkk-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas solution with [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) and [`Index.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.any.html):

```
df.index.isin(List).any()
```